# Backbone.js events from .create and serialize a form

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm using backbone.js to know when I try to submit a form. In this event, I cant use `this`. So I'm hoping to use the argument to serialize the form contents to json.

How do I do this?

```
window.UserView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: 'body',
    model: new window.UserList,
    template: _.template($('#user-view-template').html()),
    events: { "submit form#newUser": "addItem" },
    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'update', 'addItem');
        this.model.bind('refresh', this.render);
        this.update();
    },
    render: function () {
        $("#listContainer").html(this.template({ users: this.model.toJSON() }));
        return this;
    },
    update: function () {
        this.model.fetch();
    },
    addItem: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var person_attrs = $(e.target).serializeObject();
        this.model.create(person_attrs, {
            success: function (saved_person, data) {
                if (data.Result == "Success") {
                    alert("success, new Id: " + data.Model.Id);
                }
                else {
                    //Need to remove the model from the collection
                    alert(data.Message);
                }
            },
            error: function (aborted_person, response) {
                alert("Server Error");
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

So far, I got the form to serialize and send to the server. Is this the right way to do that?

I also have a few other problems:

1. Remove or cancel the local create model if the server returned an error.
2. If the server result is "Success", I'd like to assign the returned Id to the model.
3. Refresh the view. I thought the event `refresh` would be called after the server returned.

Comment: Are you using Zepto or jQuery for DOM manipulation (FYI - you should be)?

Comment: Making a question overly long or complicated tends to discourage answers.  Short and focused is much better.  You need to read about the parse method for models which would take care of your id attribute.  The view will not refresh unless you bind a view method to the model's change event.  You need to read about event binding in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd be interested in why you cannot use 'this' in your function.  If you've registered your submit event within your view, you might have something that looks like this:

```
events: {
  "submit form": "onSubmit"
},
```

where the DOM event will be wired to the onSubmit function.  The onSubmit function might look like this:

```
onSubmit: function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var attrs = this.serialize();
  if (this.model.set(attrs)) {
    // Do something here.
  }
},

serialize: function() {
  return {
    message: $("textarea[name='message']").val()
  };
}
```

where you could use JQuery selectors in your serialize method to acquire the attributes and then set them in your model before saving it.  You could also just save it if desired.  There may be more elegant ways to get the form data, but this is the technique I always use.

Comment: But I'd like to serialize the whole form that was called. I'll update my question

Comment: I added some more problems I ran into.

Comment: You serialize the whole form by adding the necessary properties and selectors within the return hash.  I only showed one as an example, but you can take it as a minimal example.